# When and where should I unregister broad cast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have `aAsyncTask` as shown below in the code and its task is to enable bluetooth adapter. In onPreExecute I registered for the action `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` to  get notified about the power state of the bluetooth adapter (on, off, turning on, turning off). This receiver is unregistered in `onPreexecute` "so that when the  asynctask finishes it unregister the receiver" and in on cancelled "so that if the back button is pressed the task will be cancelled and the receiver should be
unregistered".

However, while the task is running and I press the back button to cancel the running task, I receive the below logcat errors despite the receiver is unregistered in `onCancelled`.

Why that is happening and how to fix it?

**code**:

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");

    if (this.mATEnableBT != null && this.mATEnableBT.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        this.mATEnableBT.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Log.w(TAG, "onBackPressed");

    finish();
}
..
..
..
private BroadcastReceiver mBCR_POWER_STATE_CHANGED = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED"));

        final int prevPowState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

        switch (prevPowState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "prevPowState: STATE_ON"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "prevPowState: STATE_TURNING_ON"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "prevPowState: STATE_TURNING_OFF"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "prevPowState: STATE_OFF"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.ERROR:
                Log.e(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "NO_PREVIOUS_POWER_STATE"));
                break;
        }

        final int currPowState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (currPowState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "currPowState: STATE_ON"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "currPowState: STATE_TURNING_ON"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED: currPowState: STATE_TURNING_OFF"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.v(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED: currPowState: STATE_OFF"));
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.ERROR:
                Log.e(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED", "NO_CURRENT_POWER_STATE"));
                break;
        }

        if ((prevPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON) && (currPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)) {
            Log.i(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED: BT-Power ON"));
        }
        if ((prevPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF) && (currPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)) {
            Log.i(TAG, SubTag.msg("mBCR_STATE_CHANGED: BT-Power OFF"));

            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

**asynctask**:

```
private class  ATEnableBT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    private int mWaitTime = getApplicationContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.int_max_wait_time);
    private int mSleepTime = getApplicationContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.int_sleep_time);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.w(TAG, "onPreExecute");

        registerReceiver(mBCR_POWER_STATE_CHANGED, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.w(TAG, "doInBackground");

        mBTAdapter.enable();

        while(!isCancelled() && mBTAdapter.getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON && this.mWaitTime > 0) {
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            this.mWaitTime -= this.mSleepTime;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.w(TAG, "onPostExecute");

        unregisterReceiver(mBCR_POWER_STATE_CHANGED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        super.onCancelled(aVoid);
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled");

        unregisterReceiver(mBCR_POWER_STATE_CHANGED);
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread: Activity com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$1@3f2f9d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread: android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$1@3f2f9d that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:960)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:761)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:2002)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1982)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1976)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$ATEnableBT.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:36)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:108)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3024)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:325)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:609)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:619)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20893)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
02-13 11:45:44.948 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
02-13 11:45:46.158 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 W/MainActivity: onCancelled
02-13 11:45:46.168 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.com.bt_11, PID: 25978
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$1@3f2f9d
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:822)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:2025)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:528)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$ATEnableBT.onCancelled(MainActivity.java:65)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.com.onprepareoptionsmenu_01.MainActivity$ATEnableBT.onCancelled(MainActivity.java:26)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:630)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
02-13 11:45:46.178 25978-25978/com.example.com.bt_11 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Did you tried to call the cancell before the finish() method? By the logs it seems that onCancelled() is being called too late... Try to move the call to cancel method to onBackPressed method

Comment: @GuilhermeP i tried what u suggested but i received the same error..what i concluded is, oncancel() is asynch method

Comment: Humm.. It makes sense.. Maybe, you should move your register and unregister method to the activity.. Or add some logic to wait until broadcast is cancelled...

Answer (score 0):

One important thing here is "Doesn't matter your AsyncTask is cancelled or not". Whenever you register a **BroadCastReceiver** you must unregister it *(regardless of your AsyncTask status)*

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //without any condition. 
    unregisterReceiver(mBCR_POWER_STATE_CHANGED);
}
```

Comment: ok i know that i have to unregister any registered receiver...but i registered the receive in onprexecute and i think it should be unregistered in onPostexecute and oncancelled..am i right?